# how to process a column and return it as part of a query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table Part(No,Desc,Draw).

I want to return a list of all the parts in the table in this form :

```
Part Number| Description | Is Packed ? (Yes/No)|
------------------------------------------------
```

In the result set, the Is Packed header should be Yes if the Draw column is not null and No if otherwise.

I'm using PL/SQL.

I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT No AS "Part Number", Desc AS "Description", 
CASE 
WHEN Draw IS NOT NULL THEN 'Yes'
ELSE 'No'
END AS "Is Packed"
FROM Part
```

You might need to escape `Desc` in field list since it's a reserved word.

Comment: If he'd actually used `desc` as a column name, he'd get `ORA-00904: invalid identifier` when creating the table, but it's a good point to mention.

Comment: @BQ, it's entirely possible to do, if the column name is in double-quotes in the table create script.  Unfortunately, I often see double-quoted object names in scripts we receive from one of our vendors.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to `CASE` (see other answers) in this case you can use `NVL2`:

```
SELECT No AS "Part Number", Desc AS "Description", NVL2 ( DRAW, 'YES', 'NO' ) AS "Is Packed" FROM PART
```

BTW: you should neve create a DB object (table/column...) with a name which is a reserved word (in you case `Desc`) - this can lead to really strange things...

Comment: If he'd actually used `desc` as a column name, he'd get `ORA-00904: invalid identifier` when creating the table, but it's a good point to mention.

Comment: @BQ, it's entirely possible to do, if the column name is in double-quotes in the table create script.  Unfortunately, I often see double-quoted object names in scripts we receive from one of our vendors.

Answer (score 1):

Use `CASE`:

```
CASE WHEN Draw IS NOT NULL THEN 'Yes'
     ELSE 'No'
END AS column_alias
```